# Allow customers to print and order immediately after checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, print

I would like to give my customers the ability to print their order after a successful check out in Magento 1.8.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In checkout success page, the print link has been already available for register customer by default.

In [success.phtml](https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/master/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml#L40) file,there is a condition which  will only work for logged in customer.

Answer (score 0):

See this excerpt from `success.phtml` file, which is the key template file in order success page.

```
<?php if ($this->getCanViewOrder() && $this->getCanPrintOrder()) :?>
    <p>
        <?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">here to print</a> a copy of your order confirmation.', $this->getPrintUrl()) ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
    </p>
<?php endif;?>
```

It is clear from the above code that, print link will be shown only when `$this->getCanViewOrder() && $this->getCanPrintOrder()` is true. In short, this will become true only when follwing conditions are met.

- Customer is logged in state (means, it won't show for a guest checkout)
- If the order state is a visible state.

By default, these are the **visible states** in Magento:

- new
- processing
- complete
- closed
- canceled
- holded
- payment_review

And **invisible states** are:

- pending_payment

This means, all states except `pending_payment` are in visible mode and most of the cases, a new order state will be either `new` or `processing`.

This makes customer logged in status vital to show print order link.

Hope that helps.